Apple re-routing my private e-mail to their servers
Today I was checking my server logs and noticed that images in e-mails that I had sent to myself from my own web app were not being served by the web app server that hosts those images but instead from 172.224.224.0 which is the Apple iCloud Private Relay in London.
I have never heard of Private Relay but apparently it is an opt feature that is basically a VPN. I'm sure I have not opted into to any of this but in Mac Mail "Hide My IP address" was ticked.

Even though this appears to be a separate option from using Private Relay it still is re-routing content via an Apple IP.
I do low level work on e-mail servers as my job and was very surprised to see this, does anyone know to what extent my e-mail data is kept on these Apple servers. Does it keep the text and images and for how long?
I presume they aren't storing my account details on my server. I don't have an iCloud account but hope they have some other anonymisation process.
Either way this option is presented as if it doesn't involve any kind of VPN and could do with being clearer.

Private Relay reroutes web requests like a VPN, it doesn‘t store data. But besides that: what is your actual question here?

There is a question in my question if you care to read the question.


Email is not private,
It's the job of email servers to store copies of your emails.


E-mail is private what are you talking about, that is why it has passwords and SSL certificates.

I think this is due to how "Hide my address" works in Mac Mail. This works by making all requests for remote content through Apple's proxy server. This apparently uses the same infrastructure as Private Relay, so you see the request come from that IP.
It should be a passive proxy, like public VPN services, so it won't store anything on Apple's servers. But I can't make any guarantees, you'll have to trust Apple. If you don't, you could instead sign up for a VPN service that you do trust, and turn off that option in Mac Mail.

That option should really say, use Apple VPN to hide my IP address, I don't trust Apple or whoever they have contracted to run this for them so I have turned it off. Do you know if it is on by default? It seems to be breaking a lot of GDPR rules.

@ASterlox Private Relay is not a full VPN, https://www.macworld.com/article/348965/icloud-plus-private-relay-safari-vpn-encryption-privacy.html might help to understand how it works. To turn it off in Mail, go to Settings -> Privacy and remove the checkmark. But if you don't trust Apple to implement a double-blind proxy scheme, you might not want to use macOS at all.

It's things like this that persuade me to use Linux yes.

Which parts of the email does that setting affect?  (Presumably pictures, videos, and other content which isn't embedded in the body of the email?  But not the email body itself?)

@gidds I think so, although it's possible that they route the entire IMAP connection through their servers. But people don't usually need to hide their location from their own ISP, just third parties.

@ASterlox I think it's off by default.

I like this answer - +1
